Reformulation of Fano's Inequality in terms of pairwise bounded relative entropy -- proof?
On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano%27s_inequality, it's stated without reference or attribution the following "alternate formulation" of Fano's inequality:
If X is a random variable equal to one of a finite family of densities $f_1,...,f_{r+1}$, and that
$D_{\texttt{KL}}(f_i || f_j) \leq \beta$, then for any estimator of the index $\psi(X)$:
$\sup_i P_i(\psi(X) \neq i) \geq 1 - \frac{\beta + \log{2}}{\log{r}}$
where $P_i$ is the probability under $f_i$
This seems like a neat fact to me but there doesn't seem to be a proof provided. Someone on the talk page asked for one a decade ago but they received no response, and I can't seem to find any reference to it in standard information theory texts or the article's references. It's not clear to me how the pairwise relative entropy here relates to the original formulation using conditional entropy. Is this some easy equivalence I'm not seeing or some well known fact?  Is the theorem even true?

Let $M$ denote a random variable drawn uniformly from $[1:r+1]$. Suppose that $X \sim f_M$, where the $f_i$ are as defined in the question. Let $\psi : \mathcal{X} \to [1:r+1]$ be an estimator of $M$. Let $\pi := P(\psi(X) \neq M)$.
By Fano's inequality, we know that $$  H(M|\psi(X)) \le h_2(\pi) + \pi \log r.$$
Now, first note that $$ I(M;\psi(X)) = H(M) - H(M|\psi(X)) = \log(r+1) - H(M|\psi(X)).$$
But $$ I(M;\psi(X)) \le I(M;X) = D(P_{M,X}\|P_M \cdot P_X) \\= \sum_{i} P(M= i) D( f_{X|M = i}\|f_X) \\
= \sum_{i} \frac{1}{r+1} D(f_i \| (\sum_i f_i/r+1) )\\ 
\le \frac{1}{(r+1)^2} \sum_{i,j} D(f_i\|f_j),$$
where the first line is by the data processing inequality, the third uses that the marginal density of $X$ is the mixture $\sum f_i/(r+1),$ and the final line exploits the convexity of KL-divergence. Now, under the condition on the $f_i$, this means that $$ I(M;\psi(X)) \le \beta.$$
With this, we are in business: using the two expressions for the mutual information, and the bound from the latter, $$ \log(r+1) - H(M|\psi(X)) \le \beta \implies H(M|\psi(X)) \ge \log(r+1) - \beta,$$ and plugging this into Fano's inequality, $$ \log(r+1) - \beta \le h_2(\pi) + \pi \log r \le \log(2) + \pi \log r,$$ which together tell us that $$ \pi \ge \frac{\log(r+1)}{\log r} - \frac{\beta + \log 2}{\log r} \ge 1 - \frac{\beta + \log 2}{\log r}.$$
To conclude, notice that we worked with a uniform $M$, but due to this uniformity, $$ P(\psi(X) \neq M) = \mathbb{E}_{I \sim \mathrm{Unif}(r+1)}[ P_I(\psi(X) \neq I)],$$ and so $\sup_i P_i(\psi(X) \neq i)$ is then lower bounded, since the average of the $P_i(\psi(X) \neq i)$s is lower bounded.

I have often seen this statement termed equivalent to Fano's inequality, which I don't quite understand. There's a bunch of suprema thrown in that clearly make the statement weaker. However, this morally does capture the idea behind Fano, and is usually the form one needs in statistical applications, so perhaps this is only a mild hyperbole.
In any case, this form of the inequality, and a similar if not identical proof, appears in [1,2], although I think this had at least appeared in the literature by the '80s (I want to say in a book by Khasminskii, but I'm not sure). The reference [3] might also be interesting as a generalisation of this view to other $f$-divergences.
[1]: Yu, B. (1997). Assouad, fano, and le cam. In Festschrift for Lucien Le Cam: research papers in probability and statistics (pp. 423-435). New York, NY: Springer New York.
[2]: Tsybakov, A.B. (2009). Introduction to Nonparametric Estimation. Springer Series in Statistics. https://doi.org/10.1007/b13794
[3]: Guntuboyina, A. (2011). Lower bounds for the minimax risk using $ f $-divergences, and applications. IEEE Transactions on Information Theory, 57(4), 2386-2399.

Thank you so much for this thorough response (especially the detailed proof and references)! I see how it's a corollary to Fano, but it definitely isn't obvious!
